# How to find number of occurence and position of a substring in a string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I am struggling to find number of positions of a substring in a stings.
The below code provides me only the starting position of a substring in a string.
Please help me.

```
void Search(std::string SubString, vector<string> index)
{
    vector<string>::const_iterator cii;
    string temp;
    bool found = false;
    unsigned find = 0;
    for(cii = index.begin(); cii != index.end(); cii++)
    {
        temp = *cii;
        find = temp.find(SubString);
        if(find != std::string::npos)//running.find()
        {
            cout << find << endl;
            cout << *cii << endl;
            found = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if((cii == index.end()) && found)
            {
                cout << "Not found\n";
                found = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> index;
    ifstream myReadFile;
    string str, running;
    myReadFile.open("example.txt");
    char output[100];
    if (myReadFile.is_open()) 
    {
        while (!myReadFile.eof()) 
        {
            while( std::getline( myReadFile, str ) ) 
            {

                index.push_back(str);
            }
        }
    }

    while(running != "END")
    {
        cout << "To Quit type:- END\n";
        cin >> running;
        if(running == "END")
        {break;}
        else
        {
            Search(running, index);
        }

    }

    myReadFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [std::string::find reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/). Find has a second parameter, a position from which the search starts. So, just put find in a loop with the result of the previous find as second parameter until find returns std::string::npos. Something along the lines of:

```
int startpos = 0;
int finds = 0;
while ((startpos = yourstring.find(substring, startpos)) != std::string::npos)
  ++finds;
```

Comment: :- Thanks for the solution. I did it. Please find my updated answer.

Comment: you need to increment startpos on every iteration, otherwise it will keep on returning the same output for startpos.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it.
I made little changes in my `Search()`function.
Find the code below.

```
void Search(std::string SubString, vector<string> index)
{
    vector<string>::const_iterator cii;
    string temp;
    bool found = false;
    unsigned find = 0;
    static int n = 0;
    for(cii = index.begin(); cii != index.end(); cii++)
    {
        temp = *cii;
        std::string ::size_type pos = 0;
        while( (pos = temp.find( SubString, pos )) 
                 != std::string::npos ) 
        {
            n++;
            pos += SubString.size();
            cout << pos << " ";
        }
        if(n)
        {
        cout << " \n ";
        cout << *cii << endl;
        found = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if((cii == index.end() - 1) && !found)
            {
                cout << "Not found\n";
                found = false;
            }
        }
        n = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: If your SubString contains itself (partially), your code won't work as expected. Example: temp = "abababa"; SubString= "aba"; There are 3 occurrences of SubString in temp, but your code will only find 2 because you skip over the beginning of the second one with `pos += SubString.size()`. This might be on purpose, just wanted to let you know.

Comment: @DaClown:- Thanks for pointing out the bug. Surely I will look into the same.