# Having issues finding multiple substrings within a string

Tags: c++, string, substring

I am trying to write a program that compares two strings (string and substring) and incitements each time the substring is found within the string. However, using the standard:

```
if(str.find(substr) != string::npos)
{
count++;
}
```

I run into the problem that if the substring appears multiple times in the string it only increments once. So if the string is "test test test test" and the substring is "test" count only ends up being 1 instead of 4.

What would be the best way to fix this?

*Notes for context:

1) At one point I was checking the string character by character to see if they matched, but had to scrap that when I ran into issues when some words had smaller words in them.

Example: 'is' would get picked up inside the word 'this', etc

2)The larger program that this is for accepts two vectors. The first vector has a string for each element being sentences the user get to type in (acting at the main string in the example above). And the second vector has each word from all the sentences entered into the first vector (acting as the substring in the example above).  Not sure if that bit matters or not, but figured I would throw it in there

Example:

```
vector<string> str {this is line one, this is line two, this is line three};
vector<string> substr {is, line, one, this, three, two};
```

3) I'm thinking if there was some way of doing the opposite of !=string::npos would work, but not sure if that even exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find number of occurence and position of a substring in a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925756/how-to-find-number-of-occurence-and-position-of-a-substring-in-a-string-in-c)

Comment: @JaMiT those answers make use of `string::find()` but don't differentiate whole substrings from small substrings in larger words., which the OP needs

Comment: @JaMit Well, I'm sure the answer is in there... but I'm pretty lost trying to follow their code. Is there a more dumbed down version?

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is true, but I would add the word "also", as in "which the OP *also* needs". It can be tricky trying to answer two questions (how to count multiple occurrences and how to ignore proper substrings of words) at once.

Comment: @DamnGoodCake Did you look at the accepted answer? That's fairly short.

Comment: @JaMiT Yeah, I tried using the first answer with the while loop, but every time I put that in my code my program just stalls out and doesn't progress

**Update** just read the bit about incriminating the startpos. Thank you!!

Comment: @JaMit Ok, but now I'm back to the problem of smaller words being counted in larger words. So the 'is' at the end of 'this' is being counted in the 'is' accumulator

Comment: @DamnGoodCake look at the `string::find_first_of()`, `string::find_first_not_of()`, and `string::compare()` methods. Use the find methods to find the beginning and ending indexes of a whole word between desired delimiters (whitespace, punctuation, etc) and the compare method to check a substring between two indexes. Repeat in a loop to iterate through the whole string

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Ok, never used those before. From what I've read off of cplusplus.com it would look something like

string str ("this is a test)
size_t found = str.find_first_of(substring)...

And this is where I get lost. How would i be able to determine the str.find_first_not_of? 

First year student, so this is a little out of my wheel house, sorry >_>

Comment: @DamnGoodCake First, use cppreference.com instead of cplusplus.com. Second, see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop to find all of the occurances of a substring in a given string.

However, since you want to differentiate substrings that are whole words from substrings in larger words, you need to parse the string to determine the whole words before you compare them.

You can use [`std::string::find_first_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) and [`std::string::find_first_not_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) to find the beginning and ending indexes of each whole word between desired delimiters (whitespace, punctuation, etc). You can use [`std::string::compare()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) to compare a substring between those two indexes to your desired substring. For example:

```cpp
#include <string>

const std::string delims = ",. ";

size_t countWord(const std::string &str, const std::string &word)
{
    std::string::size_type start = 0, end;
    size_t count = 0;

    while ((start = str.find_first_not_of(delims, start)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        end = str.find_first_of(delims, start+1);
        if (end == std::string::npos)
        {
            if (str.compare(start, str.size()-start, word) == 0)
                ++count;

            break;
        }

        if (str.compare(start, end-start, word) == 0)
            ++count;

        start = end + 1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Alternatively, you can extract the whole words into a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and then use [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) to count how many elements match the substring. For example:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

const std::string delims = ",. ";

size_t countWord(const std::string &str, const std::string &word)
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string::size_type start = 0, end;

    while ((start = str.find_first_not_of(delims, start)) != string::npos)
    {
        end = str.find_first_of(delims, start+1);
        if (end == std::string::npos)
        {
            vec.push_back(str.substr(start));
            break;
        }

        vec.push_back(str.substr(start, end-start));

        start = end + 1;
    }

    return std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), word);
}
```

Comment: Sweet! This is exactly what I'm looking for! #BigUpsToRemy